# Conditional binding swift3 date

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a force unwrapping issue in swift and I've been fixing everything. So Ive forced unwrapped but I get this error "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'Date'. Here is the code.

```
if let createdat = (object?.object(forKey: "createdAt") as? String){
        if let pastDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(createdat)!)//Here is where I get the error{

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Date` initializer you're using doesn't return an optional (i.e. it's a non-failable initializer), you can't (and it would make no sense to) use it in a optional context (such as the `if-let` pattern).

Removing the `if-let` from your code fixes the problem:

```
if let createdat = (object?.object(forKey: "createdAt") as? String){
    let pastDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(createdat)!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Date() doesn't return an optional, it returns a date. That means you can't use

```
if let
```

You can use

```
let
```

Comment: rmaddy points to a very good explanation.